# Make sourced .bash_profile works immediately in current ssh session

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I use a macOS to connect to an Ubuntu server, after defining new .bash_profile (like upgrading node.js or making new alias), I will have to exit the ssh and login again after sourcing the .bash_profile before the updated bash to take effect is it possible to refresh the session in current terminal ssh session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just source the file by running `. .bash_profile` will do the job.

Comment: Or, since this is bash, `source .bash_profile`

Comment: @glennjackman source doesn't work, . works.

Comment: that means your shell is not bash. At a bash interactive prompt, enter `help . source` and you might notice ... certain similarities.